# Proof: mean value theorem

Tags: integration

Problem: Let $ f $ be a differentiable function on the real interval $[a,b]$.  Prove that there is a point $ x\in(a,b) $ at which $ f(b)-f(a)=(b-a)f'(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint:** Consider any arbitrary interval t<sub>i</sub> and t<sub>i - 1</sub> in a Riemann sum instead of a,b

Comment: but then where does the $(b-a)$ come in?

Comment: instead of (b-a) you'd have ( ti  - ti-1). The (b-a) term is also present in MVT, if you are curious why this term is there, you are better off looking for a formal proof of the MVT.

Comment: But then I wouldn't have proven the claim because $(b-a) $ is in it. Am I missing something:P

Comment: Ah sorry, I originally thought you wanted to know what (b-a) meant, rather than why it is there. This inequality can be rearranged into the classical MVT equation. I believe this link explains it. https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/mean_value/proof_mean.html.

Comment: okay got it, thank you!